# PySpark Unix Time to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

Tags: datetime, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I want to convert epoch time in miliseconds to **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS**  using PySpark. I tried below but I get weird conversion.

```
srcdf.withColumn("createdTime",from_unixtime(col("createdTime"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
```

For example, 1696012940095 got converted to +55714-07-06 09:34:55.000 while it should have been 2023-09-29 18:42:20.095 . Looks like that's because this function only takes epoch time in seconds as input. Question - How do I get the miliseconds level granularity?

Comment: Your number is in units of milliseconds (as evidenced by 095 in the low digits).  Try dividing by 1000  before converting it.

Comment: I tried dividing it by 1000 but the outcome was correct only until the seconds part. It ignored the miliseconds and gave as .000. However this worked -

srcdf.withColumn("createdTime",(col("createdTime")/1000).cast("timestamp"))

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
srcdf.withColumn("createdTime",(col("createdTime")/1000).cast("timestamp"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).